# Is there any other store like appstore to upload iphone apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I tried to upload the apps in appstore but it needs 5000 rs/ year for creating an account. Can anyone please tell me whether do we have any other iphone appstore other than appstore.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For Apple; no there isn't another (legal) App Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for **alternative stores for iOS**. But if you target legal ios(iPhone/iPad) devices, you have to use AppStore of Apple

**EDIT** I tried to share a link of lmgtfu.com but it didnd't let me share that content, so in my answer there is somtehing like "here are some alternative stores" sorry for sharing that without fixing.